# Quartz not firing jobs, but continuously updating next_fire_time

Tags: quartz-scheduler, quartz

We have a Quartz Job on Production that is supposed to run once every hour.

The prev_fire_time in triggers table is about 2 months ago, next_fire_time is continuously being updated every hour but the Job is not actually fired. The status is in "WAITING" state though.

misfire_instr is seen to be set as 0.

How do we recover this Job?  It is mission-critical that it blocks lots of activity, please advise or give some pointers on recovering this Job.

Tried resetting the next_fire_time to a random future time, still the job not fired.